Nuxt 3 + AWS amplify hosting subfolder deploy
I have a nuxt 3 app which has a validation page in [...id].vue. This app must work under the v2 baseUrl.
the problem starts when I want to manually deploy in amplify by configuring project-config.json in my amplify folder.
If I deploy my app without the url working in v2, everything works correctly in the cloud, but when I configure my nuxt.config to generate the build in .dist/v2/ and in app I add my baseUrl in /v2/, the dynamic pages like [...id].vue stop working
it is important to emphasize that I only have this error when accessing /v2/. if in my nuxt.config I never assign this baseUrl /v2/ and my folder /v2 in dist, the problem does not exist
test
 ┣ amplify
 ┃ ┣ #current-cloud-backend
 ┃ ┃ ┣ awscloudformation
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ build
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ awscloudformation
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ build
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ root-cloudformation-stack.json
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ hosting
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ amplifyhosting
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ amplifyhosting-template.json
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ root-cloudformation-stack.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ hosting
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ amplifyhosting
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ amplifyhosting-template.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ amplify-meta.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ backend-config.json
 ┃ ┃ ┗ tags.json
 ┃ ┣ .config
 ┃ ┃ ┣ local-aws-info.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ local-env-info.json
 ┃ ┃ ┗ project-config.json
 ┃ ┣ backend
 ┃ ┃ ┣ awscloudformation
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ build
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ awscloudformation
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ build
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ root-cloudformation-stack.json
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ hosting
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ amplifyhosting
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ amplifyhosting-template.json
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ root-cloudformation-stack.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ hosting
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ amplifyhosting
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ amplifyhosting-template.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ types
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ amplify-dependent-resources-ref.d.ts
 ┃ ┃ ┣ amplify-meta.json
 ┃ ┃ ┣ backend-config.json
 ┃ ┃ ┗ tags.json
 ┃ ┣ hooks
 ┃ ┃ ┣ post-push.sh.sample
 ┃ ┃ ┣ pre-push.js.sample
 ┃ ┃ ┗ README.md
 ┃ ┣ cli.json
 ┃ ┣ README.md
 ┃ ┗ team-provider-info.json
 ┣ pages
 ┃ ┣ validate
 ┃ ┃ ┗ [...id].vue
 ┃ ┗ index.vue
 ┣ public
 ┃ ┣ favicon.ico
 ┃ ┗ robots.txt
 ┣ server
 ┃ ┗ tsconfig.json
 ┣ src
 ┃ ┣ amplifyconfiguration.json
 ┃ ┗ aws-exports.js
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┣ app.vue
 ┣ nuxt.config.ts
 ┣ package-lock.json
 ┣ package.json
 ┣ question.md
 ┣ README.md
 ┗ tsconfig.json

in my nuxt.config I have:
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
 compatibilityDate: '2024-04-03',
 devtools: { enabled: true },
 app: {
   baseURL: '/v2',
 },
 nitro: {
   // preset: 'aws-amplify',
   static: false,
   output: {
     publicDir: './dist/v2',
     dir: './dist/v2',
   },
 },
});

and that configuration when executing an npm run generate gives the following error in the path /v2/validate/id
error 404 the requested path could not be found
but if I change my nuxt.config configuration to:
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  compatibilityDate: '2024-04-03',
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  // app: {
  //   baseURL: '/v2',
  // },
  nitro: {
    // preset: 'aws-amplify',
    static: false,
    output: {
      publicDir: './dist',
      dir: './dist',
    },
  },
});


My page works correctly validate
The page works correctly
My amplify configuration is
{
  "projectName": "test",
  "version": "3.1",
  "frontend": "javascript",
  "javascript": {
    "framework": "vue",
    "config": {
      "SourceDir": "src",
      "DistributionDir": "dist",
      "BuildCommand": "npm run-script generate",
      "StartCommand": "npm run-script serve"
    }
  },
  "providers": [
    "awscloudformation"
  ]
}

and in my redirect configuration I have /<*> to / with 404 rewrite
I would greatly appreciate your help and advice. Thank you.
I configured my Nuxt 3 app with a base URL of /v2 and adjusted the output directory to generate in dist/v2. I expected that the dynamic route [...id].vue would work correctly under this configuration when deployed to AWS Amplify. However, when accessing routes like /v2/validate/id, I received a 404 error, indicating that the requested path could not be found. When I reverted the configuration to omit the base URL, everything worked as expected, and I could access the routes without issues.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Also take the [tour].
